# Is there a way to turn on/off protected range view programatically using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way using Google Apps Script GAS to turn on/off the 'Protected Ranges' view to give the stripped effect?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeap. The documentation has some pretty good examples, not going to post any of my own.
Link to documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question isn’t clear enough. I know how to do the protections, it is the turning on/off of the stripes I was wondering about if you could do programmatically